# Convert arrays of string

Tags: arrays, r, string, dataframe

I have an array of string as given below. How to convert both array in data frame to use in R?

```
str1=list("6203811823616", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6196564066304", "0", "6203811823616")

str2=list("6203811823616, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0, 6196564066304, 0")
```

**output looks like:**
**df2=**

```
  str2
1 6203811823616
2 0
3 6196564066304
4 0
5 6196564066304
6 0
7 6196564066304
8 0
9 6196564066304
10 0
11 6196564066304
12 0
13 6196564066304
```

**df1=**

```
  str1
1 6203811823616
2 0
3 6196564066304
4 0
5 6196564066304
6 0
7 6196564066304
8 0
9 6196564066304
10 0
11 6196564066304
12 0
13 6196564066304
14 6196564066304
15 0
16 6203811823616
```

Comment: I want to convert it to dataframe.

Comment: @Soheil, sorry, its not working.

Comment: Please provide your complete expected output.  Also, assigning vectors with `[]` is not valid R code, that looks more like Python - please correct.  Finally, can you confirm that `str1` is a vector of many strings, whereas `str2` is a vector of only one string?

Comment: @Soheil, calss(str2) is character. And when I am doing data.frame(str2). I am getting whole string in 1 row.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear what is the desired output.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Do you want two separate data frames?

Comment: @andrew_reece, yes, str1 is a vector of many strings whereas str2 is a vector of only one string. Yes, I want two separate dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `df1` is straightforward.
For `df2`, you'll need to split the string representation of the string vector using `strsplit`, and then `unlist` to get in a vector format.

```
df1 <- data.frame(str1)
df2 <- data.frame(str2 = unlist(strsplit(str2, ", ")))
```